# Where can I find the text of the 1756 Vaad haArba Artzot / Brody Cherem?

Tags: history, cherem

I searched the web and couldn't find the text of the 1756 Cherem by the Vaad Arba Artzot excommunicating Sabbateans and limiting certain Kabbalah study.

In particular, I didn't find it even *mentioned* at

1. [daat.ac.il](http://www.daat.ac.il/encyclopedia/value.asp?id1=1117)
2. [He:Wikipedia](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%9D_(%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%99)#%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A2%D7%93_%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95)
3. Halachipedia.com (no main article on Cherem or Vaad Arba Artzot)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it. As I previously wrote in the comments, a vast number of the Vaad's letters were published by Yisrael Halperin in פנקס ועד ארבע ארצות (Pinkas Vaad Arba Aratzot). As it happens, I'm looking for a certain letter myself and borrowed a copy from my yeshiva's library. There are actually two about the Brody (and other towns') Cherem, both from 1756 (emphasis mine) (note that Brody is called here בראד or Brode):

1. Letter no. 752, which is a letter that mentions the cherem:

> ""--לאה"ג--מהור"ר יעקב נר"ו יאיר.
>
> אחד"ש כו'. ע"ד המאמינים בש"ץ ימש"ו נמסר לידי כתב מהרב הגאון מוהר"ר מאיר אב"ד דק"ק הארדענקיע מה שכתב לק"ק **בראד** והעתק מן גב"ע מגוף הכתב של הרב הגאון אב"ד דק"ק סאטנוב וב"ד יצ"ו, שנתגלה קלונם ברבים.-- וגם נוסח חרם הגדול מה שהחרימו בק"ק לבוב ובק"ק לויצק ובק"ק **בראד** ובק"ק דובנא ובכל הגלילות, כמבואר בספר הכלבו, על איזה איש או אשה **שהוא מן הרשעים הנ"ל ויעשה עמם שידוך או יתעסק עמהם במו"מ או שיאכל ממאכלם יהיו מוחרמים כמוהו. וגם כל שנים שיודעים על אחד שהוא מכת הרשעים הללו מחויבים להעיד בב"ד לפרסם הדבר. וגם חל החרם על כל מי שילמוד ספרי מינין האלו ספרי הר"ן ומ"ן ופרוש התקיעות שלהן וספר הפסול ואבוא אל העין. וכל מי שיש בידו ספרי טומאה הנ"ל או נוסח הקמיעות החדשים אשר לא נשמע ולא נראה דוגמתם, חל עליו החרם אם לא ישרוף הן ואזכרותיהן.**
>
> גם יחול החרם הנ"ל על כל מי שיגלח דינרי זהב מוחרמים ומופרשים מכל קדושת ישראל, וגם העתק התפלה שמתפללים לברחיה ימש"ו. וכהיום נמנו וגמרו להחרימם בכל גבול ישראל קודם כל נדרי. --
>
> הפרנס הוועד הק' ר' אברהם מק"ק לובלין ובנו הר' פנחס מתחרטים על הראשונים ואומרים מה נאמר ומה נדבר שהשטן הסית בנו וכמה היזיקות היו לנו בנפשות ובממון מצדי צדדים, שכל הכתבים הראשונים היו שמעלילים עליו דברי שקר וכהיום נתבאר בעליל שהוא יונתן בכור שטן המסטין את ישראל. וזירז להכריז החרם בועד הקודש על ספריו ועל הקמיעות. אני הייתי בק"ק קאסטנטין משך שתי שבועות אצל מחו' מוהר"ר ברוך נר"ו, שהיה רעש גדול ע"י הבלבול מה שנתעורר בק"ק יאמפלי, שנלכדו במצודה רעה בבלבול עלילות שקר כמו בפאבליטש. ולקחו כל פני העיר בשלשלאות של ברזל, המקום ירחם עליהם, אשר כל בית ישראל ענו ואמרו כי בעון זה נשפך דמם של ישראל באותו גליל. מחמת אותו רעש הוכרחתי להמתין עד שיוכרז בבה"כ. והרב מו' פנחס הבטיח שיודפס בק"ק זאלקוויא חרטתו והכרוז והחרם.--
>
> כ"ד הדש"ת הק' יצחק הח"ק בייאלה לע"ע". (pg. 416-417)

2. Letter no. 753, which is the text of the cherem:

> ""נוסח החרם שנתנו בבית הכנסת הגדולה בק"ק **בראד** ביום התענית ך' סיון וכמו כן הכריזו אותו בעת האסיפה דד"א בב"ה בקאסטנטין וזהו תוכן נוסחו (חדוש שנדפס זה החרם ג"כ בכ' סיון):
>
> החרם של כלבו כידוע כם תקיעת שופר וכיבוי נרות כנהוג, ותוכן הדבר שהחרם חל על כל מי ומי מבני המאמינים בש"ץ שהוא משיח והמאמינים בברכי', שר"י ונתן העזתי הנביא שקר להם שחיק טמא, עדת כלבים בנים שובבים, ופשיטא שחל החרם על אותן המהפכים דברי אלהים חיים, סחי ומאוס עושין תורת משה ותלמוד רבינא ורב אשי, כי חק להם לצמיתות, לעבור על חייבי מיתות ב"ד וכריתות. גם חל החרם על מי שיודע על איזה איש או אשה שהוא מן הרשעים הנ"ל ויעשה עמם שדוך או יתעסק במו"מ או שיאכל ממאכלם, יהיה מוחרם כמוהם. גם כל שנים מישראל היודעים על אחד שהוא מן כת הרשעים האלה מחויבים להעיד ברבים לפרסם הדבר, כדי להבדילו לרעה מכל עדת ישראל. גם חל החרם על כל מי ומי שילמוד ספרי המינים האלה הנקראים ספרי מהר"ן ומאורות נתן, וכוונת התקיעות שלהם, וספר פסול המכונה ואבוא היום אל העין, וכל מי שיש בידו ספרי טומאה הנ"ל בו כיוצא בהן חל עליו החרם, אם לא ישרוף הן ואזכרותיהן. גם החרם חל על ממציא הקמיעות הטמאות, וכן גזרו בחרם שהחשוד על האמונה הכוזבת הזאת בקלא דלא פסיק, חלילה לו להורות הוראה בשום מקום, ואסור לשמוע הוראתו בין להקל בין להחמיר, גם אסור להורידו לפני התיבה בשום פעם, גם לא יחזיק שום תלמידים, ולא יהא סופר סת"ם, ולא שוחט ובודק, אם לא שיודע בבירור גמור שעזב את דרכו הרעה של אנשי כת ש"ץ שר"י ועשה תשובה גמורה משך שנה תמימה. והבלתי שומע יהא נלכד במצודת החרם הנ"ל. והכריזו על נשיהם ובנותיהם שהם זונות ובניהם ובנותיהם שהם ממזרים, גם דור עשירי לא יבוא להם בקהל ה', פפ"כ ויי"ן ומרק פגולים כליהם. גם חל החרם על כל מי ומי שחותכין ממטבעות מהיום והלאה וכו' כנאמר בכל בו. **גם גזרו שלא ללמוד ס' הזוהר ושום ספרי קבלה, הן בדפוס הן בכתב, קודם שימלאו שלשים שנה ואף אחר ארבעים לא כל הרוצה השם יטול, לא הותר אלא למי שמלא כרסו ש"ס ופוסקים.** וצוה להכריז כרוז הנ"ל בכל ער"ח בכל מקום אשר דבר המלך מלכו של עולם ודתו מגיע (גוף הנוסח ארוך יותר וכבר בא בדפוס ואנו קצרנוהו שלא להטריח הקורא בחנם). וחתומים על החרם גדולי פולין". (pg. 417-418)

If you need info on some of the things here, there are footnotes by Halperin that I can copy and translate for you.

Comment: So that text is abbreviated, as stated at its end there?  Because the one in Oliver's answer in Otzar Hokhmah 1859 begins, 
לקול המולה. קןל ענות ויללה...
Seems odd it would be abbreviated in the Pinkas which ought to be a complete Register of the Vaad, no?

Is there an image somewhere? I see it's at https://kotar.cet.ac.il/kotarapp/index/Book.aspx?nBookID=98982655 but it requires an account to view.

Comment: @NissimNanach The text was abbreviated by whoever wrote it, not by Halperin (Halperin had no problem bringing very long texts). This is apparently the version that was handed out in the towns. If you want, I can take pictures and upload them to my drive and link them.

Comment: Yes, that'd be great, and any footnotes and translations are also appreciated.

Comment: @NissimNanach https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E_koxJLEajl160N60rKzQaTPxzKjFmNZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @NissimNanach Translating everything would be a lot of work...but if there's anything specific, then I'd be happy to assist.

Answer (score 4):

The original and complete text of the excommunication* (“Herev Pifiot”) can be found [here](https://www.nli.org.il/he/journals/NNL-Journals001129895/NLI) on page 22 of the journal Otzar Hochmah, pub. 1859.

*Not to be confused with that produced in R. Emden’s ‘Sefer Shimmush’.